# Unprotected Access to Onedrive from Office Hub

Tags: onedrive, office

My Winphone is a Lumia 532 Dual SIM Win 8.1.

I have noticed that it is possible to **access my Onedrive without any password** request from the Hub *Office>Places>Onedrive* .

In this way, anyone who has my phone in its own hands might access my Onedrive, read, delete, edit, download my document, stored there.

The question is: How to avoid all that unless to block with a PIN code the telephon itself?

Comment: Have you set a PIN in the OneDrive app?

Comment: Yes, I have sey the PIN code but it block unwished access to OneDrive in case I (or somebody else) enter it, tapping the Onedrive tile. What I want is** to block the access to Onedrive from the Hub Office**. The same, I would like** to block unpassworded access to the Skype application**.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you can't delete files from the Office Hub. But you are right, if you can secure the OneDrive app with a pin this should also be possible for the Office Hub. You should post this as a suggestion on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thomas, thank you for the suggestion. I will post soon my request to Mama Microsoft!